# Прочитать содержимое Infinispan Cache

Tags: java, кэширование, jboss

Я использую Infinispan Cache в моем Java-проекте.
Можно ли каким то образом получить содержимое Infinispan Cache?
Я искал внешние библиотеки, которые решают эту задачу, но безуспешно.

Я хочу открыть страницу в браузере и посмотреть содержимое, объекты, текущее использование в ОЗУ, expired/не expired, какое время expired для каждого и сколько их в системе.

Аналог того, что я хочу - jvisualvm, но он не удобен, есть проблема с подключением к проекту и нет веб-интерфейса.

Есть какое либо решение этого вопроса?